# Class constants in Python

Tags: python, class, constants

In Python, I want a class to have some "constants" (practically, variables) which will be common in all subclasses.

Is there a way to do it with friendly syntax?
Right now I use:

```
class Animal:
    SIZES=["Huge","Big","Medium","Small"]

class Horse(Animal):
    def printSize(self):
        print(Animal.SIZES[1])
```

and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it?
or a way to do it without then having to write "Animal." before the sizes.

Horse inherits from Animal.

Comment: Not a full answer but If `SIZES` never changes, definitely use a tuple instead of a list. Like so `("Huge","Big","Medium","Small")`

Comment: Looks like you're really after an enum here

Comment: @jamylak your comment seems to be popular, many people seem to consider it valueable. Could you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @dmigo Just that the question was asking about constants and a list can be mutated, so it's better to use a tuple which is immutable. A constant should not change

Answer (score 196):

Since `Horse` is a subclass of `Animal`, you can just change

```
print(Animal.SIZES[1])
```

with

```
print(self.SIZES[1])
```

Still, you need to remember that `SIZES[1]` means "big", so probably you could improve your code by doing something like:

```
class Animal:
    SIZE_HUGE="Huge"
    SIZE_BIG="Big"
    SIZE_MEDIUM="Medium"
    SIZE_SMALL="Small"

class Horse(Animal):
    def printSize(self):
        print(self.SIZE_BIG)
```

Alternatively, you could create intermediate classes: `HugeAnimal`, `BigAnimal`, and so on. That would be especially helpful if each animal class will contain different logic.

Comment: SIZE_BIG=["BigOne","BigTwo"] shall i use this type of  constant.

Answer (score 28):

You can get to `SIZES` by means of `self.SIZES` (in an instance method) or `cls.SIZES` (in a class method).

In any case, you will have to be explicit about where to find `SIZES`. An alternative is to put `SIZES` in the module containing the classes, but then you need to define all classes in a single module.

Comment: Horse is indeed a subclass of Animal. Actually, it is perfectly possible to use self.SIZES[1] instead of Animal.SIZES[1].

Comment: @betabandido: the OP corrected the question. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

```
class Animal:
    HUGE = "Huge"
    BIG = "Big"

class Horse:
    def printSize(self):
        print(Animal.HUGE)
```

Comment: Also you can access via self, ex. "self.HUGE" or "self.BIG". This would only work internally within the class.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on betabandido's answer, you could write a function to inject the attributes as constants into the module:

```
def module_register_class_constants(klass, attr_prefix):
    globals().update(
        (name, getattr(klass, name)) for name in dir(klass) if name.startswith(attr_prefix)
    )

class Animal(object):
    SIZE_HUGE = "Huge"
    SIZE_BIG = "Big"

module_register_class_constants(Animal, "SIZE_")

class Horse(Animal):
    def printSize(self):
        print SIZE_BIG
```

Comment: `print SIZE_BIG` out of class will be the same? Will it be editable `Animal.SIZE_HUGE = 'Small'`?